# Joining two dataframes and filling values with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1:
          Value 1
0  Team_1   5
1  Team_2   8
2  Team_1   10   
3  Team_3   9
4  Team_2   3

df2:
          Value 2
0  Team_1   21
1  Team_2   32
2  Team_3   53
```

I'd like to join them so that I get the following:

```
          Value 1    Value 2
0  Team_1   5           21
1  Team_2   8           32
2  Team_1   10          21
3  Team_3   9           53
4  Team_2   3           32
```

I'm assuming I'll have to perform a join of some sort but I'm not sure which type I should use and whether I'd need to take any steps after that to get the desired output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried already? [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) is a good page to have a look at.

Comment: `df3 = df1.copy(); df3['Value 2'] = df2['Value 2']` or `df1.join(df2)`?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

df1

```
team value_1
Team_1 5
Team_2 8
Team_1 10   
Team_3 9
Team_2 3
```

df2

```
team value_2
Team_1 21
Team_2 32
Team_3 53
```

Use simply `pd.merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2)
```

result:

```
     team  value_1  value_2
0  Team_1        5       21
1  Team_1       10       21
2  Team_2        8       32
3  Team_2        3       32
4  Team_3        9       53
```

It works because dataframes share the same column `team` in my case.